# Refresh FirebaseUser after changes made on server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase on both Android and iOS and after I register a user, I pass the username I took from the user, to my server to update the displayname. This works, but it's not visible on the app until the user closes the app or logs out.

I have tried using the [`reload` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#reload()) which states

> Manually refreshes the data of the current user (for example, attached providers, display name, and so on).

But this doesn't do anything.

Is there another way of refreshing/reloading the data, or maybe clearing the cache?

It's possible that I could add the displayName in the app itself, but as I limit the displayname based on availability of names in my server, it makes sense to do it there.

UPDATE: (have added some code examples)

I update the displayname in a java app using the admin sdk like this

```
    private void updateUsernameInFirebase(String uniqueId, String username){
        UserRecord.UpdateRequest request = new UserRecord.UpdateRequest(uniqueId).setDisplayName(username);
        try {
            UserRecord userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().updateUser(request);
        } catch (FirebaseAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then try to refresh the data in my Android client app like this

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(firebaseUser != null) {
    Task<Void> reload = firebaseUser.reload();
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Which part do you need me to add @FrankvanPuffelen a code example? I've stated what is not working (after updating displayname on server it's not updated in client app). I'll add a very simple bit of code now...

Comment: You'll need to show us what isn't working,. The second snippet now shows that you call `reload()`, but not what isn't working about it. A statement like "this doesn't do anything" is really hard to help with. But if you including some code that logs a value, and then say "I expected this to log abc, but instead it's logging xyz" we're more likely to be able to help.

Comment: Ok, I'll add another bit, but isn't it quite clear that I'm trying to update the displayname field of a user and when i do that on the server the change isn't in the client?